# How do I install the plugins to play music and videos on my Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet)

Tags: plugins

I am trying to play music and videos, and it is saying plug-in missing. I have tried to play the songs while connected to the Internet, but no change.

Answer (score -1):

Install **Ubuntu restricted extras**. use the following [link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/) and install via Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: What format of audio and video are you trying?